# HTML5 Details-> Summary

Tags: javascript, html

Pretty basic question here.

I'm using HTML5's DETAILS and I was wondering if the SUMMARY could be changed whenever it's clicked.

ie...

Summary shows "Show more" but I was wondering if there was a way to have it display "show less" after it's been clicked and the details are shown.

```
<details>
   <summary>Show more</summary>
   <p>Content></p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in simple HTML but in JavaScript(JQuery)

```
$('summary').click(function(){
   if($(this).text() === 'Show more' ){
      $(this).text('Show less');
   }else{
      $(this).text('Show more');
   }
});
```

you can add jquery to your page by adding this tag that links to their CDN before the mentioned code.

```
<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Though I never had any reason to avoid jquery since it's already used in parts of the application, I was just curious to see if there was an HTML5 only option to do this. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

try this with jquery

```
var clicked=false;
    $("summary").click(function(){
    if(!clicked){
   clicked=true;
    this.html("show less");
    }else{
   clicked=false;
   this.html("show more");
   }
    });
```

without jquery

```
       var clicked=false;
        var a=document.getElementsByTagName('summary')[0];
        a.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(!clicked){
        clicked=true;
        a.innerHTML="show less";
       }   else{
   clicked=false;
        a.innerHTML="show more";
        }
        },false);
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. this is a simple solution.

Comment: Should note that this requires jquery as the OP did not say that he was using jquery.

Comment: Though I never had any reason to avoid jquery since it's already used in parts of the application, I was just curious to see if there was an HTML5 only option to do this. Thanks guys!